# Extracting numbers from inbetween two brackets

Tags: string, extract

Had difficulty with the following, please help.

On excel I am trying to use a formula where I can extract the numbers that are between the open and closed brackets in multiple cells, however the amount of letters in the description in each cell vary, and the amount of numbers in between the brackets also vary. Here is an exact extract from the generated report..

1 x Drill Cub (10324) 
      ()

Also if possible I would be able to also extract two lots of numbers between multiple brackets in a cell as in the example below…

1 x aerial amplifier **^ (211566) 
      ()
1 x The angel of the night and right angle  (213215) 
      ()

Further example….

1 x Durrytal Lamny Sheep Bottle | Colours Listed (204274) 
      ()
1 x Durrytal Lamny Sheep Bottle | Colours Listed (9821) 
      ()
1 x Durrytal Lamny Sheep Bottle | Colours Listed (204280) 
      ()
1 x Durrytal Lamny Sheep Bottle | Colours Listed (204289) 
      ()
1 x Durrytal Lamny Sheep Bottle | Colours Listed (9842) 
      ()

Comment: What programming language? You said you had difficulty, so can you show us the code you have so far and the difficulty in particular?

Comment: Sorry, am not sure I understand the question. I have just been trying to use an excel formula to extract the numbers I want from a cell. Does that help you?

Comment: Yes that helps, you should probably mention that somewhere in your question! You could look at using the `FIND()` function which gives you the position of a character in a string. Once you know the position of the brackets you can just select the string in between.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try and edit. As I mention though the position of the brackets vary each time as the description before the brackets vary. Is it possible just to find the brackets and then extract any length number combination that are inbetween?

Comment: Found a fix.... =MID(G847,SEARCH("(",G847)+1,SEARCH(")",G847)-SEARCH("(",G847)-1).